# input field: store decimal values with comma instead of a point in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, localization

I have an input field for a price. The entered value will be stored into a database, for example `13,99`.

In the MySQL database this field has the type `decimal(10,2)`.
What happens is that the price will only be stored correctly into the database if the user types `13.99` with a point instead of a comma. If the user types `13,99` it will be stored as `13.00`.

What should I change in my code, so that the user can also type `13,99` and it will be stored correctly into the database?

```
<?php
...
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE products  set price =? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($price,$id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $price = $data['price'];

    Database::disconnect();
}
?>
...

  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($priceError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Preis</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="form-control" name="price" type="text"  placeholder="price Number" value="<?php echo !empty($price)?$price:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($priceError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $priceError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Easiest solution is to replace comma with dot before inserting into database.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do this exactly?

Comment: And how did he differentiate decimals with commas @HardeepPandya

Comment: str_replace(",",".",$price); this will replace comma with dot and if there is no comma then value will be as it was.

Comment: Do you mean into the input?: `<input class="form-control" name="price" type="text"  placeholder="price Number" value="<?php echo !empty(str_replace(",",".",$price))?$price:'';?>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
...

if ($valid) {
        $price = str_replace(",",".",$price);
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE products  set price =? WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($price,$id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $price = $data['price'];

    Database::disconnect();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the "locale", the decimal point, thousands separator, etc, should change.

`DECIMAL(10,2)` does not include '.' or ','.  That is a formatting issue.

You can also use the third option on MySQL's [`FORMAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) if you like.